# callback is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

In this code I have a `callback undefined` error:

```
function getPacakage(callback){
var sendurl={address:'http://ip/bms/data.php?result=10&order=28'}
var temp_selpkg_group=[];
var temp=[];

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"dummycall.php",
        data:sendurl,

        success:function(xml){              

            pkg_sel[0] = $(xml).find('test1').text();
            pkg_sel[1] = $(xml).find('test2').text();
            pkg_sel[2] = $(xml).find('test3').text();
            $(xml).find('packageitem').each(function(){
                temp_selpkg_group=[];
                temp_selpkg_group[0]=$(this).find('group').text();
                temp_selpkg_group[1]=$(this).find('Qty').text();
                temp[cnt_pkgitem]=temp_selpkg_group;
                cnt_pkgitem++;                  
            });

            callback.call(null,temp);
        },//sucess ends

        error: function(){
            alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
        }   //error ends..  

    }); //ajax ends...  

}
```

Here is how I'm calling the function:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });     

    getPacakage(function(temp){
        sel_pkg_group=temp;
        fillOptionList();
    });

});//document ready ends..
```

If I refresh page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) 2 to 3 time then the data is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ajax is an asyc task we need to complete one ajax task first and the call the function to use the array which is intialized in ajax ,so just add **async:false** in ajax.

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"dummycall.php",
        data:sendurl,
        async: false,
        success:function(xml){  ..............
```

this will stop async and the other methos will be called only when one complete , this works for me may be helpfull to my other friends ,happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line -

```
callback.call(null,temp);
```